# How to install graphical environment to work simultaneously with Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: 12.04, server

I have a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 (only console as this is supposed to be my server) and now I also want to add a graphical environment on this machine.

More details:

1. I want the main OS to be the: Ubuntu 12.04 console as it is now and
2. by typing commands on this console to open a graphical environment
   (I prefer Ubuntu 12.04 desktop) in order to access the internet more
   easily without having to search from another PC

I was thinking of installing a virtual machine from my Ubuntu console and
then installing Ubuntu desktop on this virtual machine.

Can anyone please tell me if this is feasible and how can be done?

Comment: @burnttoast11: I don't want to replace my CLI with a graphical one. I want to have both of them. By typing sudo apt-get install gnome-shell (in order to install GNOME) I will lose my CLI and be replaced by gnome?

Comment: Also I want to have easy access from one interface (CLI) to another (GNOME). It would be perfect if I was able to navigate from one interface to another without having to reboot in order to change interface.

Comment: @kt456, you may use Ctrl+Alt+F1~F6 to which to terminal and Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch to GUI